# Razor Syntax not rendering Multi-Statement code nugget

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor, html-helper

Hello guys I have this weird problem with Razor Syntax.

I have written the same code nuggets in Razor syntax ,having only difference in Inline expression and Multi-statement block.

***About.cshtml***

```
   <!-- Single statement blocks -->
   <p>
       Put content here.
       @Html.SubmitButton("You are in About")
   </p>
```

**Rendered Output:**
[image]

***Index.cshtml***

```
<!-- Inline expressions BUT DOESNT WORKS-->
@{ Html.SubmitButton("okay in Index");}

<!-- Multi-statement block BUT DOESNT WORKS-->

@{ 
   Html.SubmitButton("You are in Index");
   Html.CheckBox("A Check Box");
 }
```

**Rendered Output:**
[image]

**P.S:** Ignore the input button text in the snapshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The htmlhelpers only *return* values.

Even inside code blocks, you still need the `@` to tell Razor what to do with those values (print them to the HTML buffer).

So never-mind with the code block in this case, it would be redundant, as there's no other code in there but the html-helpers.

But even if there were other code to be placed within the block, you'd still need to preface the helpers with `@`:

```
@{
    var myVar = "something";
    // and so on ...

    @Html.SubmitButton("You are in Index");
    @Html.CheckBox("A Check Box");
 }
```

Comment: That's strange ,`var` statement and `Html.Submit("")` both are valid C# statements then why treat them differently ?

Comment: They're not really being treated differently. Without the `@`, Html.CheckBox *is* doing what it's supposed to do -- return a string, which you can then capture and manipulate if you want to. `@Html.CheckBox(...)` is just shorthand for `Response.Write(Html.CheckBox(...))`

Comment: So put it simple anything I wanna render as html ,I can append it with `@` symbol ?

Comment: Any c# value that can take `.ToString()` should work this way, I believe. So in my code, you could output `@myVar` this way. Razor recognizes HTML tags, and will automatically output them without either the @ or `Response.Write`, but plain text (w/o any surrounding tag markup) requires the @ for Razor to make sense of it.

Comment: More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx